# How to Pinch - Zoom in and Zoom out a image openened in android app in Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

Here's the test scenario i'm trying to automate on the app but got stuck,

- Open the app & go to photos section (Working)
- Tap on photo view it (Working)
- To confirm the photo is loaded, I want zoom in and zoom it out (Not Working)

Appium version: 1.4.16.1
API Level 19

Below is the code snippet:

```
@Test
 public void openph() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc='Navigate up']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='3']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@index='1']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='2']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.CheckedTextView[@text='Photos only']")).click();
        List<WebElement> ops = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView"));
        ops.get(2).click();
        driver1.zoom(25, 45);
        driver1.pinch(25, 45);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }
```

Can anyone please help me to get fix this.

Currently it's throwing nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly because you have two different drivers (`driver and driver1`)? Appium is currently able to run one driver on one session at a time.

Also I don't know what you are doing with these lines:
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

You only need to start that once per driver (it also isn't very good as it will slow down your tests a lot, it would be better to use a `WebDriverWait(Driver, <defined wait time>`

Comment: Hey Jayson, Thanks for your input, I tried using appium driver alone this time to use zoom() method, This time i'm not getting any error but image is not zooming in though.For my test pass assertion i need image to be zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Use this below the code it work fine.
 import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

 public class Zoom_and_pinch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File app= new  File("D:\\Testing\\com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample.apk");
    //Launch app
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities= new DesiredCapabilities();

            //device details
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "GT-I9300I");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");

            //app details
            capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());


            //appium server details
            AndroidDriver driver= new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

            //wait
            Thread.sleep(4000);

            driver.findElementById("com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample:id/basicFeatures").click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);

            WebElement ele_image = driver.findElementById("com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.sample:id/imageView");


            int x1= ele_image.getLocation().getX();
            int y1= ele_image.getLocation().getY();

            System.out.println("x is "+x1+"y1 is "+y1);

            int x=ele_image.getLocation().getX()+ele_image.getSize().getWidth()/2;
            int y= ele_image.getLocation().getY()+ele_image.getSize().getHeight()/2;

            //Zoom
            TouchAction finger1= new TouchAction(driver);
            finger1.press(ele_image, x, y-20).moveTo(ele_image, x, y-200);

            TouchAction finger2= new TouchAction(driver);
            finger2.press(ele_image, x, y+20).moveTo(ele_image, x, y+200);

            MultiTouchAction action= new MultiTouchAction(driver);
            action.add(finger1).add(finger2).perform();

            Thread.sleep(8000);

            //Pinch
            TouchAction finger3= new TouchAction(driver);
            finger3.press(ele_image, x, y-200).moveTo(ele_image, x, y-20);

            TouchAction finger4= new TouchAction(driver);
            finger4.press(ele_image, x, y+200).moveTo(ele_image, x, y+20);

            MultiTouchAction action2= new MultiTouchAction(driver);
            action2.add(finger3).add(finger4).perform();

   }

 }
```